# How to represent a "choice" as a WFormModel::Field

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, model, model-view, wt

By "choice" I mean something akin to `<xsd:choice>`; that is, a selection from among multiple specific items.

I know there's WAbstractListModel, but that doesn't offer any way to represent a chosen/selected item, and I can't determine how (or even if) it's meant to relate to a WFormModel::Field.

One could in theory have a WFormModel::Field and document the model to require that the field's value be taken from a particular list model.  But that seems pretty "loose."  It would be nice to enforce that restriction in the code somehow.  I guess you could write some validation logic to enforce that restriction, but I would hope you could do it declaratively rather than having to write logic.

Are there any examples of this out on the web?  (I'm aware of the WComboBox/WFormModel examples, but I'm specifically looking for a way to restrict the choice strictly within the model itself.)